# X is the largest sum of rupees which can never be paid using any number of coin of denominations Rs. 4, Rs. 8, Rs. 13 and Rs. 18

Tags: combinatorics

'X' is the largest sum of rupees which can never be paid using any number of coin of denominations Rs. 4, Rs. 8, Rs. 13 and Rs. 18. What is the sum of digits of 'X'?

Answer is 9. But how?

I could got up to the denominations which are in form of 4, 4K+1, 4K+2...then there is the problem.

Comment: This is called the frobenius number: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNTSugyS038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4$ is the least of these numbers, so your best bet for paying n is **smallest number you can pay, with the same remainder modulo $4$ as n**, plus **a lot of $4$s**. Examine what numbers can be on the left.

$n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ is uninteresting.

$13 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

$18 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Finally, $3$ can be either $1+2$ or $1+1+1$. That is $13 + 18 \equiv 13+13+13 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Clearly $13 + 18 = 31$ is the smaller of them and thus the smallest number you **can** pay, with remainder $3$, modulo $4$. The number you **can't** pay, is the one before it - namely $27$.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that every even number 16 or larger can be made: 16 is 8+8, 18 is 18, 20 is 8+8+4, 22 is 18+4, etc.  14 Rupees can't be made because the only denominations smaller than it are 13 (too large to help), and 4 and 8 (both multiples of 4).

Now, being able to make every even number above 14 means that every odd number larger than 27 can be made as 13+even number.  But 27 can't be made; it must involve exactly one 13-rupee coin (3 13-rupee coins would be too large and two would leave an even number), and so would be made as 13+14 - but we've already established that 14 can't be made.  This shows that 27 can't be made, and we've already covered all the numbers larger than 27.

Answer (score 0):

Any number larger than $(13-1)(4-1)=36$ can be written as a non-negative combination of $13$ and $4$ Rupees. The largest number that cannot be written this way is $35$ . But adding coins of values $18$, or $8$ will not change that ( everything you can get with $8$ you canget with $4$, and $18$ is even, so it will not help you find a combination that adds up to $35$. So the answer is $35; 3+5=8$ Maybe they meant the least number so that every other number can be paid with those coins; this number is $36$.

Edit: As pointed out by Steve Stadnicki, $35=4+13+18$ . We also have that

$34=26+8$ ; $33=13+20$ ; $32=4.8$ ; $31=13+18$ ; $30=18+12$ ; $29=13+16$; $28=4(7)$

And $27$ cannot be done by Exhausting the cases ( $13+18=31; 13+4+4+4+4=29; 13+8=21$

After we have four consecutive, we can form any number by adding multiples of $4$ to it.

Comment: But solution shows the answer is 27, and that is why summation of digit is 9.

Comment: 35 rupees is 4+13+18.

Comment: O.K, I corrected it, but it may be pointless by now.